# Permissions to deny SSH users from accessing other user's folders

Tags: linux, permissions, access-control

I am currently running Fedora on a network computer, acting as a host to other users who will SSH into my terminal to do their work.

However I realised that they are also able to access my `/home` folder. How do I go about setting the permissions such that they are not able to access it?

Answer (score 6):

By making it not world readable. By default it looks like so:

```
igalic@tynix /home % ls -lh
total 28K
drwxr-xr-x. 62 igalic igalic 4.0K Jun 20 10:24 igalic/
drwx------.  2 root   root    16K Jun  1 15:54 lost+found/
igalic@tynix /home %
```

I can deny anyone but myself (and root) access with `chmod o-rx`:

```
igalic@tynix /home % ls -lh
total 20K
drwxr-x---. 62 igalic igalic 4.0K Jun 20 10:28 igalic/
drwx------.  2 root   root    16K Jun  1 15:54 lost+found/
igalic@tynix /home %
```

These are the basic Unix permissions. You can do more fine-grained access-permissions with extended POSIX ACLs:

```
igalic@tynix /home % getfacl igalic
# file: igalic
# owner: igalic
# group: igalic
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---
```

Or SELinux:

```
drwxr-x---. igalic igalic unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 igalic/
drwx------. root   root   system_u:object_r:lost_found_t:s0 lost+found/
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i realised my user could simply use something like chmod 0775 <myfoldername> to change back the settings. Is there any other function to deny him from changing permissions himself?

Comment: Are you saying the other people will connect with *your* user? That makes it virtually impossible for you to deny them access!

Comment: I think i understand what is going on. Apparently,the user was using the sudo command to change my folder permissions such that it is resetted to default. Looks like i need to disable the user from the sudo list....

Comment: @JohnTan If you put a user on the sudo list (as in: allowing them to run any command as any user), they can do anything they want. That's the whole point of sudo!

Answer (score 4):

Words like *permissions* or *access* are too vague for a Unix system. In order to solve your problem, you would need to learn how permissions are managed, and then define more precisely what you mean by *"not able to access it"*.

#### Short overview of the permission system on Unix

There are 3 kinds of permissions:

- `r`: read
- `w`: write
- `x`: execute

Note that the permission have special meaning for directories:

- `r`: list the files in the directory,  for instance with `ls`.
- `w`: add new elements to the directory.
- `x`: access files in the directory.

There are 3 levels of permission you can set:

- user (the owner of the file/directory)
- group
- all

Note that when you create new users on the system, you're asked to assign them a group. The reason is simply for a better management of permissions.

#### How to know the permissions of a file

There are various ways. I think the most straightforward would be using `ls -l`. Example:

```
$ ls -l file
-rw-r-----   1 rahmu users   406 Jun 18 13:28 file
```

The first column indicates the permissions.

`-rw-r-----`, the first bit (`-`) indicates whether the file is a directory, a link or a regular file. Ignore it for now. Then the next 3 bits (`rw-`) indicate the user-level permissions. That means user `rahmu` has the right to `read` and `write` this file. The next three bits (`r--`) are the group-level permissions, this means that all the users who are in the group `users` will have `read` access. All the other users will have no permission at all (`--`). That means they cannot read the file, write it, nor execute it.

#### How to modify permissions.

It is usually done with the `chmod` utility. It supports many syntax, which one is best is debatable, but the following will make most sense after the above explanation:

```
$ chmod [who]operator[permissions] file
```

- `who` is `u`ser, `g`roup or `o`thers. (there's also `a`ll, for modifying all three levels at once).
- `operator` is `+` or `-`.
- `permission` is `r`, `w` or `x`.

Examples:

- `chmod u-w file`: remove `write` permission for user.
- `chmod a+x file`: add `execute` permission for all.

#### How to prevent *access* to your /home?

As I mentioned, you need to define what you mean by *access*. If what you mean is `read` access, as in you don't want them to even list what's inside your directory, then the easiest would be to take the appropriate permissions off the `/home` directory. (Assuming they're connecting with a separate user).

```
$ chmod o-rwx ~
```

Comment: Note that the execute permission on a directory controls whether you can access files in that directory. That it is the permission for `cd` is an anecdotic additional side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Each file (and directory) belongs to a user and a group, always. To manage access control there are three sets of rights: one for the user the file belongs to, one for the group the file belongs to and one for everyone else (other).

Check our home-directory for its permissions, `ls -l /home`. Most likely your home-directory belongs to your username, which means whether or not others can access it depends on the group-rights and other-rights. Everybody who has read rights on your home-dir can retrieve a list of its contents, everybody with executable rights can access files in that directory.

To be as restrictive as possible set your home-directory permissions to 700 with `chmod 700 /path/to/your/home` This make your home-dir inaccessible for every user that is not you.

SSH has nothing to do with this!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to install 3rd party apps, you should take a look at the [limited shell (lshell)](http://lshell.ghantoos.org/). It can be configured to limit users' access to commands and/or paths in your file system.

It can also detect if a connection is done remotely (over SSH, FTP, ...) and act differently accordingly.

I cannot give you an exact configuration to your use case, but I suggest you take a look at the description of [all the available options](http://lshell.ghantoos.org/Configuration), as well as the [sample config file](http://lshell.ghantoos.org/Use%20case) hosted on the project's website.