# How to check which Apache group I can use for the web server to write?

Tags: permissions, chmod, apache-httpd

I'm trying to make Wordpress work. I currently have this error message:

```
Could not create directory. /var/www/html/wp-content/upgrade/theme_name
```

when trying to upload a theme. This is the permissions set to `/var/www/html/wp-content/upgrade/`

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 ec2-user apache 4096 Jun 21 00:30 upgrade
```

`chmod 777 upgrade` makes the error go away. But that is not considered best practice. However, I think this should work too... why not?

I guess the web server may not be included by the above permissions. What group should I use to allow the web server to write?

(My setup is Amazon EC2, Amazon Linux AMI with httpd)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know anything about Amazon EC2, but you should be able to:

1. Retrieve the name of the user running Apache with a command similar to this:

   ```
   ps aux | grep apache # The username should be in the first column.
   ```
2. Retrieve the groups this user is part of with the `groups(1)` command:

   ```
   groups [USERNAME]
   ```

Comment: The first column is apache, and groups apache return apache : apache. A line from the first commmand looks like this:
apache   11171  0.0  3.4  39984 21516 ?        S    Jun20   0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd

Comment: User apache clearly has permissions to write in the directory. You say `chmod 777` solves the issue, so I am guessing you're using a different user to upload your themes. I don't know Wordpress very well. According to [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23174/could-not-create-directory-wp-content-upgrade) try changing ownership to user `www-data`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look up the article and everything. It was indeed a different user, as I realized Wordpress used FTP to do its work. I found out that user by what was suggested below and then added group apache, found out by step 1, to it. That solved it.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use the following command-line method to find out your Apache group names:

```
WWW_GROUP=`ps axo user,group,comm | egrep '(apache|httpd)' | grep -v ^root | cut -d\  -f 2| uniq`
echo Apache group is: $WWW_GROUP
```

To get the user, check: [How to determine Apache user from the command-line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155549/how-to-determine-apache-user-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

> chmod 777 upgrade makes the error go away.

Well, in that case `ls -ld /var/www/html/wp-content/upgrade/theme_name` should reveal creator's credentials, which you can use for precise access granting.

And it's better using `1777` (as for `/tmp`) since at least it guarantees that only owner of a file would be able to unlink it.

Comment: Make the error go away! Interesting approach to problem solving. This is not a solution, it's a lie.

Comment: What do you call "lie" — citing original author's text? :) or suggestion to at least use 1777 instead of 777? :) or finding out creator ownership and using it for "precise access granting"?

Comment: It's a lie to the system, because `777` is not correct in any context I know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one liner for this to stuff in a test or subshell or something, this works well:

```
ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v "$(whoami)" | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}' | groups | awk '{print $2}'
```

In the above, the last command selects the 2nd group, because the first is typically `sys`, which is not generally useful.

If you want a list of *all* groups that apache is in, drop the last pipe section `awk '{print $2}`, like so:

```
ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v "$(whoami)" | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}' | groups
```

If you want the apache username, do the previous and also drop the `groups` pipe section, like this:

```
ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v "$(whoami)" | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

---

I do not suggest making assumptions about the environment unless it is fully under your own control. If you need to programmatically determine the user and are not absolutely certain that it will always run in a specific environment (or are not certain that someone may have changed it to some custom name/group in their apache.conf), then it is practical to have some uniform method to check for it. You can stuff this in a `.env` file under some common key for localized program access, or alternately echo it into `bash_profile` or `bashrc` if you want a consistent variable to check systemwide, perhaps like this:

```
echo export "WEBSERVER_USERNAME=$(ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v "$(whoami)" | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}')" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo export "WEBSERVER_USERGROUP=$(ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v "$(whoami)" | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}' | groups | awk '{print $2}')" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Elsewhere: ...

```
# chown a dir to the webserver universally
# for typical 755 directory permission
# Good for production environment web app folders
sudo chown "${WEBSERVER_USERNAME}:${WEBSERVER_USERGROUP}" /path/to/dir

# chown to your user and the webserver usergroup
# for shared 775 cli/http directory perms
# good for dev environment, localhost, or anywhere that
# you have to do a lot of cli file edits to web folders/files
sudo chown "$(whoami):${WEBSERVER_USERGROUP} /path/to/dir
```

or whatever else you need it for without having to look it up a million times