# How to determine Apache user from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, apache-httpd

There is a question about the [group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41241/find-web-server-group-permissions-problem), but I couldn't find any question/answer for getting the Apache user.

Therefore how to determine Apache user from the command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use the following command-line method to find out your Apache user name:

```
WWW_USER=`ps axo user,group,comm | egrep '(apache|httpd)' | grep -v ^root | cut -d\  -f 1 | uniq`
echo Apache user is: $WWW_USER
```

---

To get the Apache group, simple change the `cut`'s field number from `1` to `2`, see: [How to check which Apache group I can use for the web server to write?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41241/wordpress-cant-create-directories-below-upgrade).